# Two data.tables number of matching columns

Tags: r, data.table

If I have two data.tables, `dt1`, and `dt2`, I want the number of matches between columns using an if then sort of logic. If `dt1$V1==dt$V2`, then does `dt$V1 == dt$V2`? But it is key for this if-then statement to group by the matches in `dt1$V1 == dt$V2`. I would like to use data.table for its efficiency, since I actually have a large dataset.

```
dt1 <- data.table(c("a","b","c","d","e"), c(1:5))
dt2 <- data.table(c("a","d","e","f","g"), c(3:7))
```

In this dummy example, there are 3 matches between the V1s, but only two within those groups for V2s. So the answer (using `nrow` perhaps, if I subset), would be 2.

Comment: If my output was a data.table of the matching answers, that would be best.

Comment: Of course I can merge the data.tables. Then I would use some sort of group subset with "by". Something like: "by=dt1$V1==dt2$V2"  is the logic I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: @akrun No. IMHO it is not a clear duplicate, because OP didn't ask to merge/join. OP asked to find common elements. So, now you are accusing me of your own standard practise?

Comment: @akrun Even if _one of the answers_ is using inner join it doesn't mean that the _question_ is a duplicate. And none of the answers in your duplicate mentions `fintersect()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for `fintersect`:

```
fintersect(dt1,dt2)
```

gives:

> ```
>    V1 V2
> 1:  d  4
> 2:  e  5
> ```

To get the number of rows, add `[, .N]`:

```
fintersect(dt1,dt2)[, .N]
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] 2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not pretty, but, it works:

```
sum(dt1[V1 %in% dt2$V1]$V2 ==   dt2[V1 %in% dt1[V1 %in% dt2$V1]$V1]$V2)
```

Just read your comment, if you want a data.table with the correct combinations you can make it even longer, like this:

```
dt1[V1 %in% dt2$V1][dt1[V1 %in% dt2$V1]$V2 ==   dt2[V1 %in% dt1[V1 %in% dt2$V1]$V1]$V2]

    V1 V2
1:  d  4
2:  e  5
```

I'm definitely looking forward to see other answers :)

Answer (score 1):

We can just do a `join`

```
dt1[dt2, on = names(dt1), nomatch = 0]
#   V1 V2
#1:  d  4
#2:  e  5
```

---

or `inner_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(dt1, dt2)
#  V1 V2
#1  d  4
#2  e  5
```

---

Or with `merge`

```
merge(dt1, dt2)
#   V1 V2
#1:  d  4
#2:  e  5
```

---

For all of the above the number of matches can be find by `nrow`

```
nrow(merge(dt1, dt2))
```